# Run perl command in external server using ssh

Tags: bash, perl, unix, ssh, aix

I want to run a perl command at a remote location using SSH

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
ssh $RFTPUSERID@$RFTPSERVER /bin/bash >> ${LOGFILE} << EOF
cd ${ARCHIVEPATH}
find  ${ARCHIVEPATH} -type f -mtime +${ARCHIVERETENTIONDAYS} -name "${WLDCRD}*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
ls ${ARCHIVEPATH} | grep -v gz$ | perl -lne '$date=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`; chomp($date); `mv ${ARCHIVEPATH}$_ $_$date`;'
find ${ARCHIVEPATH} -type f ! -name "*.gz" -exec gzip {} \;
exit
EOF
```

The first command is able to delete the old files and third command is also able to zip the files, but the second command which appends the date to filename using perl functionality is not working.

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Ex. is perl in the user's PATH?  Did you print the arguments perl received?  Does your `ls ... | grep` return something you expect?  Your `...| grep -v gz$` will probably cause problems, `$` means something to the shell.  Double quote and backslash are required.

Comment: @SharadR.Telkar : The remote part of a script uses a variable `date`, but you don't set it.

Comment: @Nic3500 : I think the _gz$_, while certainly not good style, is harmless here. Since a space follows the `$`, it is not interpreted by the shell. Try for instance `echo $`.

Comment: @user1934428: yes he does, first instruction in the perl: `$date=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`;`  it is not pure perl, but should be ok.  But for the question, there is a quoting problem here.  The quotes for the date command close the quotes for the perl.  Remove these quotes around the date spec string.

Comment: @SharadR.Telkar: Also, _is not working_ is not a very meaningful description of a problem. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for learning, how to ask a sensible question on [so].

Comment: @Nic3500 : A, you are right. Sorry. This is a Perl expression (`-e` flag). And you are also right about the mismatched quotes. The OP tries to nest single quotes inside single quotes. No wonder that it does not work....

Comment: You could `xargs` or reformat your code and not use perl at all, since you only seem to be renaming files with an extra date...

Comment: @SharadR.Telkar Accept the previous answers if you're using them in your current script.

Answer (score 1):

Your script can be written to be much more robust (And a bit simpler) as:

```sh
#!/bin/ksh -x
ssh "$RFTPUSERID@$RFTPSERVER" /bin/bash >> "${LOGFILE}" << EOF
shopt -s extglob
cd "${ARCHIVEPATH}"
find  "${ARCHIVEPATH}" -type f -mtime "+${ARCHIVERETENTIONDAYS}" -name "${WLDCRD}*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
date="\$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')"
for file in "${ARCHIVEPATH}"/!(*.gz); do mv "\$file" "\${file##*/}\$date"; done
find "${ARCHIVEPATH}" -type f ! -name "*.gz" -exec gzip {} \;
exit
EOF
```

You generally always want to quote variable expansions to prevent unwanted side effects, and looping over the result of filename expansion is [far, far better](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) than trying to handle the output of `ls`. And when all you're doing in a perl script is calling other programs... there's no point in using perl over shell.

The double parsing of the script, first by the local `ksh` and then by the remote `bash`, does make things a bit more complicated... hence the escaping of the variables in the loop and the command substition of `date`.

Comment: The last find to gzip files can probably be removed and the gzipping moved into the loop if you don't have a directory tree to search through.